# Parallel database tests with peewee and postgres in python

Tags: python, postgresql, integration-testing, cherrypy, peewee

I'm trying to paralellise my database integration tests but I'm unsuccessful. I'm using cherrypy, peewee, postgres and nosetest.

My base model (every entity derives from this one):

```
 class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = manager.get_db()  # Link this to the loaded database.
```

my manager class looks like that (manager (lower case) is the singleton instance of DbManager)):

```
class DbManager(object):
    db = None

    def initialize_db(self):
        return PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase(None, max_connections=10, threadlocals=True, register_hstore=False)

    def get_db(self):
        if not self.db:
            self.db = self.initialize_db()
        return self.db
```

my base database test (patching refers to that aforementioned singleton manager instance) :

```
class BaseServiceTest(unittest.TestCase):
    _multiprocess_shared_ = True

    def setUp(self):
        self.begin_patch = patch('manager.db.begin')
        self.begin_mock = self.begin_patch.start()

        self.commit_patch = patch('manager.db.commit')
        self.commit_mock = self.commit_patch.start()

        self.rollback_patch = patch('manager.db.rollback')
        self.rollback_mock = self.rollback_patch.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.rollback_patch.stop()
        self.commit_patch.stop()
        self.begin_patch.stop()
        manager.get_db().rollback()
```

in the test-top-level **init**.py file I'm setting up database:

```
def set_up_database():
    settings = {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5432,
    "name": "product_test",
    "user": "product_test",
    "password": None,
    'sslmode': 'disable'
    }
    load_db_only(settings)
    reset_db_only()
```

load_db_only invokes initialize on database with specified parameters, reset_db creates necessary relations

the problem is - data is shared among tests, so I'm getting failing constrains (this email already exists etc.) when I run parallel tests.
What I'm trying to achieve is having data in transaction only (in general my goal is to have tests running in parallel - so any other suggestions are very welcome):

- transaction starts
- I'm putting some test data in transaction
- test runs (gets data from transaction process it, updates etc.)
- transaction is rolled back
- everything looks like my test never happened

So finally my question is:
Does Anyone have any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Are you sure your patches are working as expected? You might try calling `manager.db.set_autocommit(False)` in your setUp() method as well.

Comment: I'm affraid it didn't help. Still duplicate entries.